# Input out of range for Int datatype, not passing a testcase

Tags: kotlin, bit-manipulation

I am trying to solve the following question on LeetCode; Write a function that takes an unsigned integer and returns the number of '1' bits it has. Constraints: The input must be a binary string of length 32.

I have written the following code for that which works fine for inputs `00000000000000000000000000001011` and `00000000000000000000000010000000` (provided internally by the website) but give output `0` for input `11111111111111111111111111111101` and in my local compiler for the last input it says "out of range"

```
 class Solution {
    // you need treat n as an unsigned value
    fun hammingWeight(n:Int):Int {
        var num = n
        var setCountBit = 0
        while (num > 0) {
        setCountBit++
        num= num and num-1
           
        }
        return setCountBit
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please use  only the relevant tags while you are posting a question. Ex: You have added Java and Kotlin both tags for a source code which was written by Kotlin.

Comment: sorry next time I will take care. Used Java as many Java programmers are comfortable with Kotlin and many are even learning Kotlin who are working on Android.

Comment: @AkashKumarRoy those Java devs interested in Kotlin should then follow the Kotlin tag. So don't bother with the Java one :)

Answer (score 1):

To correctly convert binary string to `Int` and avoid "out of range error", you need to do the following (I believe LeetCode does the same under the hood):

```kotlin
fun binaryStringToInt(s: String): Int = s.toUInt(radix = 2).toInt()
```

`"11111111111111111111111111111101"` is equivalent to `4294967293`. This is greater than `Int.MAX_VALUE`, so it will be represented as negative number after `.toInt()` convertion (`-3` in this case).

Actually, this problem could be solved with one-liner in Kotlin 1.4:

```kotlin
fun hammingWeight(n: Int): Int = n.countOneBits()
```

But LeetCode uses Kotlin 1.3.10, so you need to adjust your solution to handle negative `Int`s as well.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. But I still can't figure out how to handle the negative valued Int. And please do explain how does Kotlin convert 4294967293 as -3. I want to know about the concept behind it. I know about the concept of range for specific datatypes.

Comment: Both `UInt` and `Int` use the same amount of bits (32) to encode numbers. But they treat them differently. `UInt` just do a straightforward convertion to binary, but `Int` also needs to handle negative numbers (and do this without minus sign, because there is no sign in binary representation).

Comment: So, numbers `0..Int.MAX_VALUE` are encoded as is - from 0 to 01111111111111111111111111111111, and the following binary numbers are used to encode negative numbers from 
`Int.MIN_VALUE` (10000000000000000000000000000000) to `-1` (11111111111111111111111111111111). If you're interested in rationale behind this encoding logic, I'd recommend to read these articles: [1](https://knowthecode.io/labs/basics-of-digitizing-data/episode-9) and [2](https://knowthecode.io/labs/basics-of-digitizing-data/episode-10)

Answer (score 0):

Please change the type of your input variable from **Int to** a type like **Double** .At the moment The given value is bigger than the maximum value that a type Int number can store.

Comment: I have tried with Long too. Doesn't work.

Comment: Don't use Long use Double please see the updated answer.

Comment: Internally the website is taking input as a string, converting that into an Int and passing the input here. the error is occurring when the string is converted into int and being stored in an Int var

Comment: still not working. This is the link for the problem on leetcode; https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-1-bits/

Comment: @AkashKumarRoy it looks like a bug on leetcode side, I don't think you can do anything about it because changing the signature makes the leetcode code fail, not yours.

Comment: @Joffrey yes that can be. But if such thing we have to then how to do it? If we have 32-bit binary number as a string and we have to calculate the number of 1 bit.